# Protocol specification - correct name for the timestamp/event-counter column

Tags: embedded, protocols, firmware

I am developing a communication protocol between a Computer and a Device, using a USB connection. The device has multiple sensors, each one measuring different types of variables in different sample rates.

Each time that the measurement from a sensor is ready the Device sends a message to the Computer as follow:

| Sensor ID | Event Counter | ... | Payload |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x01 | 0x00000012 | ... | 123.123f |

This means that the sensor 0x01 will send the measurement of the event 18 (decimal). The next event will be:

| Sensor ID | Event Counter | ... | Payload |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x01 | 0x00000013 | ... | 012.120f |

Now, in a future release of this protocol the user will have the option to select between an *Event Counter* or a *Timestamp*. So, for example instead of the format above with the *Event Counter*, it will be possible to have something like:

| Sensor ID | Timestamp | ... | Payload |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x01 | 0x00004120 | ... | 012.120f |

This means, that since the device started streaming, it already elapsed 16672 milliseconds (decimal) until that event.

So, for the second column it will be an *Event Counter* or a *Timestamp*, but for the documentation, I want to have a unique name to represent that column, which must encapsulate both the *Event Counter* and *Timestamp* idea. What is the correct name for that protocol column?

| Sensor ID | (INSERT THE CORRECT NAME HERE) | ... | Payload |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x0X | XxXXXXXXXX | ... | XXXXXXf |

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is really entirely a matter of opinion what you would call that, and not really a valid SO question.  A shame because you clearly put a great deal of effort into it.  I'll happily give an opinion in a comment if not an answer.  I'd call it _Event ID_, then also have an additional enumeration field indicating the _Event ID Type_, which would be `TIMESTAMP` or `COUNT` perhaps or could be something else should you later devise some means of identifying an event.  You might also use it to specify the units, so you might have `TIMESTAMP_MIILLISEC`, `TIMESTAMP_MICROSEC` etc.

Comment: +1 for Clifford's introductory comment. -- How about "sequence marker" or similar? -- If you use a timestamp, how do you distinguish between two messages sent at the same moment? -- You might want to do some research on existing protocols to learn how they solved this problem.